# How to set patience as default git diff algorithm

Tags: git, diff

In .git/config I tried:

```
[diff]
    patience = true
```

But no luck

Do I have to do:

```
git diff --patience
git show --patience HEAD
```

etc., every time?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Since [Git 1.8.2](https://git-htmldocs.googlecode.com/git/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt), Git will use `diff.algorithm`:

```
git config --global diff.algorithm patience
```

It took a few iterations:

> [[PATCH v3 0/3] Rework git-diff algorithm selection](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/213736)
>
> [[PATCH v2 0/3] Rework git-diff algorithm selection](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/213526)
>
> [[PATCH 0/3] Rework git-diff algorithm selection](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/213294)
>
> [[PATCH] diff: Introduce diff.algorithm variable](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/192719).
>
> [[PATCH] config: Introduce --patience config variable](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/192331)

Comment: Seems that it's now in standard (well, I'm on git version 1.8.2.1)

Comment: It seems like `histogram` is a better option now. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32367597/2019549.

Answer (score 7):

In lieu of a config-based answer, you could set an alias in your `.gitconfig` like so:

`[alias]`
`dp = diff --patience`

Which will allow you to do `git dp [optional refspec]`

Comment: Thanks! not ideal though as I have to the same for `show` and maybe a few more commands - and then try and train myself to use the new versions.

Comment: Not to mention `merge`, `rebase`, etc.—the real reason I wanted to set patience diff by default. I'm pretty certain I won't mind if it takes a bit longer but I don't have as many @!#$#@ conflicts.

Comment: @EoghanM Might be appropriate at this point to change the accepted answer.

Comment: So first, OP asked how to set the **default** diff, so you're not answering the question at all. And secondly, "in lieu of a config-based answer", you give... a config based answer...