# how can I avoid weird git diffs like this?

Tags: git, diff

I sometimes edit xml-like files, like `plist`s or `xib`s, and sometimes i get diffs like [image: this one].
Instead of the diff starting with the `<dict>` and ending with the `</dict>`, it starts and ends +2 lines. This also happens sometimes with Objective-C code too. I would add a new `case` in a `switch`, and the diff will not start from `case` down to `break`, but it will again have an offset of one or two lines.
I understand that this happens because the previous and next lines are basically the same, but is there a way I can avoid this, fix this, or change its behavior in some way?
Thanks.

Comment: Are there differences in the whitespace?

Comment: no. especially in the xml style files, because they are generated by tools.

Comment: Drat, I had hoped it was that easy for you...

Answer (score 6):

Try another diff algorithm. I had good results with the
*patience* algorithm in cases like this.

Use for example:

```
git diff --patience
```

---

From the [`git-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) manual:

> **--patience**
>
> Generate a diff using the "patience diff" algorithm.
>
> **--diff-algorithm={patience|minimal|histogram|myers}**
>
> Choose a diff algorithm. The variants are as follows:
>
> *default*, *myers*
>
> The basic greedy diff algorithm. Currently, this is the default.
>
> *minimal*
>
> Spend extra time to make sure the smallest possible diff is produced.
>
> *patience*
>
> Use "patience diff" algorithm when generating patches.
>
> *histogram*
>
> This algorithm extends the patience algorithm to "support low-occurrence common elements".

---

Related:

- [How to set patience as default git diff algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4460202/2020827)
- [What is `git diff --patience` for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4045017/2020827)

Comment: I read about it, and the comparisons etc. though when applying it on my change above, I still get the same diff.

Comment: @pvinis Could you provide the two files?

Comment: old file: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=C6B3F6n9  
new file: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qPG5zCbQ  
change: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tpV1tUur